# Why you can't use two columns to select your start row when paging using the TOP/SET ROWCOUNT method UPDATED: Actually you can

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

### ORIGINAL TITLE: Why does a value like '{Bad' affect the results when used in a comparison in T-SQL?

I've created a stored procedure to handle paging of a large table.  The important parts from the procedure are below:

```
DECLARE @first_id NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @first_parent NVARCHAR(250);

SET @skip = @skip + 1

SELECT TOP(@skip) @first_id = id,
                  @first_parent = parent
FROM   [dbo].[DATA]
WHERE  RowSet = @rowset
       AND FieldID = @field_id
       AND ( parent = @parent
              OR @parent IS NULL )
ORDER  BY parent,
          id;

SELECT TOP(@max) id,
                 [Description],
                 Closed,
                 Hold,
                 Access,
                 [Type],
                 parent
FROM   [dbo].[DATA]
WHERE  parent >= @first_parent
       AND id >= @first_id
       AND RowSet = @rowset
       AND FieldID = @field_id
       AND ( parent = @parent
              OR @parent IS NULL )
ORDER  BY parent,
          id
```

It works fine unless @first_parent is '{Problem' when that happens half of the rows in the result are skipped.  Is it the '{'?  This is running on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Please provide the minimum possible sample that reproduces this issue. We can't see your data. What have you done to narrow down the issue yourself? For example have you tried just `SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM   [dbo].[DATA] WHERE  parent >= @first_parent` ?

Comment: That is the strange part the count works fine.  It also works fine when the order by only includes the id.  I'll work the minimum set.  I'm feeling like the '{' I originally thought was causing it may be a red herring though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Smith for getting me to figure out a minimum set with the issue.  The problem has nothing to do with '{' or any other character.  The problem is trying to use TOP to page with 2 columns being used to select the start row.

To highlight why using two columns won't work take the table below as an example

```
-----------------------
| Parent       |   Id |
|--------------|------|
| 1            |   1  |
| 1            |   2  |
| 1            |   3  |
| 2            |   1  |
| 2            |   2  |
| 2            |   3  |
| 3            |   1  |
| 3            |   2  |
| 3            |   3  |
-----------------------
```

You run the above stored procedure the final select, with data filled in rather than variables, will be:

```
SELECT TOP(@max) id,
             [Description],
             Closed,
             Hold,
             Access,
             [Type],
             parent
FROM   [dbo].[DATA]
WHERE  parent >= '1'
   AND id >= '2'
   AND RowSet = @rowset
   AND FieldID = @field_id
   AND ( parent = @parent
          OR @parent IS NULL )
ORDER  BY parent,
      id
```

Which when you look at is pretty obvious why not all of the expected results are returned.  So the moral is that if you are trying to use the SET ROWCOUNT/TOP method of paging you can only use one column to pick the start row.

### UPDATE: 2013-3-12

After further research/effort, it turns out you can use the TOP/SET ROWCOUNT method of paging if you can treat the columns like they were one column like so:

```
DECLARE @startat NVARCHAR(500)
SELECT TOP(@skip) @startat = COLUMN1 + <separator> + COLUMN2 + <separator> +... + COLUMNN
  FROM <TABLE>
  WHERE <WHATEVER YOU NEED> -- Optional
  ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ... COLUMNN

SELECT TOP(@max) <columns you want>
    WHERE <WHATEVER YOU NEED> AND COLUMN1 + <separator> + COLUMN2 + <separator> +... + COLUMNN >= @startat
    ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ... COLUMNN
```

@skip and @max are your paging parameters.

Separator should be a character that is less than any of the allowed characters in your data, for me CHAR(13) worked great.  It is needed because otherwise you end up with the issue outlined above.

Also note that this requires that all of the columns be text or convertible to text.  If your columns allow NULL values I recommend using COALESCE(COLUMN, N'').